# Word (365) - Any way to return to Start screen?

Tags: microsoft-word

I like to use custom templates in Word and I was wondering if there was a way to return to that screen inside an existing Word window (so after editing an open document for example) without opening a new instance?

I have both explored the ribbons and menus and online and haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Yes, Go to menu File -> New Document.

Comment: Thanks LPChip, No idea how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Go to menu File -> New Document.